# Adding Node to the End of a Linked List - C++

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I can't get this program to attach the node to the end of the linked list. I know it has to do something with the "addBack" function because the "addFront" function works perfectly. I think this should be sufficient, but if more code is required, merely ask and ye shall receive.

```
template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::addBack(const E& e)
{
    E *temp = head;
    while (temp -> next != NULL)
        temp = temp -> next;
    SNode<E> * v = new SNode<E>;
    temp -> next = v;
    v -> elem = e;
    v -> next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You have to change `E *temp = head` to `SNode<E> *temp = head`, because the `temp` is a node pointer which you walk to the end with. The compiler must have been warning you about this. Weren't there any messages?

Comment: This doesn't look right at all. `E` is the element type, not the management node type. How do you expect `E *temp = head;` to even compile, much less work (assuming `head` is a `SNode<T>*` And even if fixed, this still won't work, as it won't update the head pointer on the *initial* insertion (first insert).

Comment: And also, I recommend you to maintain a `last` pointer alongside `head`, so accessing the end can be faster.

Comment: u got any compiler error?

Comment: Oh okay... Between your comments and the answer, I think I have it figured out... And yeah, I did have compiler errors, but I haven't taken the time to learn what they reference... I know it's very ignorant of me, but in the past, the only errors I've encountered were extremely easy to correct (typically typos and whatnot)

Comment: Be careful. You're storing a pointer of a reference. Assuming that you use `slinkedlist.addBack(object)` (object is an instance) and not `slikderlist.addBack(*object)` (object is a pointer) In your code you must be sure that when you delete the referenced object (i.e. it goes out of scope) you delete it also from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two problems with this code. First the head is not a pointer of type E , instead it is pointer of type SNode.
2ndly list may be empty when first item is being added (head will be NULL). So you need to handle that case separately.
Following code should work:

```
template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::addBack(const E& e)
{
    SNode<E> * v = new SNode<E>;
    v -> elem = e;
    v -> next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL) //list is empty
        head = v;
    else
    {
        SNode<E> *temp = head;
        while (temp -> next != NULL)
            temp = temp -> next;
        temp -> next = v;
    }
}
```

However for faster insertions, you must have two pointers, both for head and tail of the list. You will not need to iterate the whole list to find the tail. However then you will have to cater for both head and tail when adding and removing a node from list.
This will be the function if you have both pointers:

```
template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::addBack(const E& e)
{
    SNode<E> * v = new SNode<E>;
    v -> elem = e;
    v -> next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL) //list is empty
        head = tail = v;
    else
        tail -> next = v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will make the necessary corrections and comment with my success (hopefully).

Comment: No such luck... I'm getting error messages for `return(ptd);` of "tidtable.c"

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but you might be able to bring light to this error for me.

Comment: I take that back... Apparently it refused to compile on my computer, but as soon as I got into lab, it immediately compiled and worked properly on the lab computer -_-

Comment: Glad to know, I hope your issue has been resolved :)